# How is the value of MediaDeviceInfo.deviceId calculated in Webrtc?

Tags: javascript, c++, webrtc

I am wondering how is the value of `MediaDeviceInfo.deviceId` calculated in `Webrtc`?

`MediaDeviceInfo.deviceId` is a property used in web APIs of `Webrtc`.

I have found a document [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo/deviceId), but still cannot get the answer.
Is it directly from the `uuid` of the connected Media Devices?

I guess there may be some calculations in native codes, but I am not familiar with its native codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Chrome implementation here:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:content/browser/renderer_host/media/media_stream_manager.cc;l=1653;drc=917850e016efe08e27c61eaa03e6fc27200e5be1

It is a hmac of the device id with a per-origin salt that has the same lifetime as cookies (for privacy reasons). This hides any device uuid.